# Error in pgsql2shp postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

I want to dump a shapefile from my postgresql database with the following command line:

```
pgsql2shp -f output.shp -h localhost -u postgres -P admin parcel "SELECT * FROM parcel.export_output WHERE ParcelNoEng=116"
```

but it goes on showing the error:

```
ERROR:  function postgis_version() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT postgis_version()
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What shall I do to get it work?
I have added Postgresql/version/bin to my environmental variable.

Comment: is the `postgis` extension properly installed?

Comment: What happens if you execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` in your postgresql?

Comment: I have installed the postgis from the stack builder itself.

Comment: I see. But don't forget that you have to create the extension in the database you wanna use with pgsql2shp (in your case, the maintenance db (!) `postgres`). If it is not supposed to be an automatic process, consider downloading the feature from postgres using QGIS and then creating your shapefile.

Comment: Thanks Jim... create extension postgis worked.

Comment: nice! would you mind if I create an answer for it, so that you can close and also benefit others?

Comment: Sure, but would like another help too. How can i get to you?

Comment: the best way to get help (also from me) post a new question. If I'm not able to answer, there others who certainly can :)

Comment: btw, I'm leaving my office in 10 min, so I won't be able to check your new question before later tonight or tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the [`PostGIS extension`](https://postgis.net/install/). Execute the following command in your PostgreSQL using a client of your choice, e.g. [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html), and try again:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```